Alternative to Windows 10/11 Mail for Exchange ActiveSync
I have several email accounts monitored through the Windows 11 Mail app (the same app exists on Windows 10 with the same features). Two of these accounts are corporate accounts that require Exchange ActiveSync functionality. I am unable to connect with a standard Exchange connection.
Microsoft has stated that the Mail app will be discontinued in 2024, being replaced by Outlook. However, Outlook does not support Exchange ActiveSync.
Is there an alternative mail client that supports Exchange ActiveSync that would allow me to monitor all the email inboxes in the same app?
